# How can we conceal the DOM from other (3rd party) scripts?

Tags: javascript, security, dom

I thought maybe I could do something like this, but it's not possible:

```
// My app module, contains ALL my app code.
// This is the first script to execute.
(function () {
  var document = window.document
  delete window.document // doesn't work. :(
  Object.freeze(window) // at least this works.

  // now my app can do whatever it needs to do, securely...
})()

// 3rd party code (f.e. Chrome extensions) can not access DOM,
// because window.document doesn't exist.
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work because we can't change the value of window.document. I also tried `document.body = null`, `document.children = null`, etc, in order to prevent the DOM from being traversed, but it's not possible.

Is there a way we can block (possibly unknown) 3rd party code so that the 3rd party code can not read our DOM?

Comment: No, not if the code is running already. If you want to prevent that from happening in the first place, look into Content Security Policy.

Comment: Chrome extensions or userscripts can run before the page gets loaded, so there will always be a way to get over any protection.

Comment: `(function(window,document,etc){  "use strict"; eval(someCode)   }());`... it's not 100% with a co-ordinated attack, but it should "bust" 99% of the things you want not to work...

Comment: @dandavis I'm guessing in your example `someCode` is 3rd party code. I'm referring to 3rd party code I don't have access to though (for example, chrome extensions or userscripts as @Gothdo mentioned).

Comment: you might be able to wrap the content on the page into a web component's shadow dom, which would certainly but down on the number of tools that could casually read the DOM... aside from that, no: if you can run, you can't hide.

Comment: @Gothdo How would we block Chrome extensions or userscripts with CSP? Also, I don't really want to block them. I just want to limit what they have access to.